# Could not retrieve uploaded images in Laravel. I created the storage link. But it wont work.Did I miss anything?

Tags: php, laravel

The image is showing as "Image Description". How I can retrieve the image which is in the database? Other than images all are smoothly working.

This is my first project. I could not find out the issue. Can anyone give a hand to sort out it?

This is my **index.blade.php**

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal-sm position-relative z-index-2 flex-row overflow-auto overflow-md-visble">
    @foreach($products as $p)
    <li class="list-group-item py-2 px-3 px-xl-4 px-wd-5 flex-horizontal-center shadow-on-hover-1 rounded-0 border-top-0 border-bottom-0 flex-shrink-0 flex-md-shrink-1">

        <a href="../shop/product-categories-7-column-full-width.html" class="d-block py-2 text-center">
            <img class="img-fluid mb-1 max-width-100-sm" src="/storage/admin/{{ $p ['prod_image_path'] }}" alt="Image Description">
            <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $p ['prod_name'] }}</h6>
            <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $p ['prod_price'] }}</h6>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="list-group-item py-2 px-3 px-xl-4 px-wd-5 flex-horizontal-center shadow-on-hover-1 rounded-0 border-top-0 border-bottom-0 flex-shrink-0 flex-md-shrink-1">
        <a href="../shop/product-categories-7-column-full-width.html" class="d-block py-2 text-center">
            <img class="img-fluid mb-1 max-width-100-sm" src="/storage/admin/{{ $p ['prod_image_path'] }}" alt="Image Description">
            <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $p ['prod_name'] }}</h6>
            <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $p ['prod_price'] }}</h6>
        </a>
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

This is my Admin\ProductsController.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

         
    public function index()
    {
        $arr['products'] = Product::all();
        return view('admin.products.index')->with($arr);
    }

   

   
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.products.create');
    }

  
    public function store(Request $request, Product $product, Category $category)
    {

        if($request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName())
        {
            $ext =$request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName();
            $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;
            $request->prod_image_path->storeAs('public/admin',$file);
        }else{
            $file ='';
        }

        $product-> prod_name = $request-> prod_name;
        $product-> prod_meta_title = $request-> prod_meta_title;
        $product-> prod_description = $request-> prod_description;
        $product-> prod_category = $request-> prod_category;
        $product-> prod_price = $request-> prod_price;
        $product-> prod_discount = $request-> prod_discount;
        $product-> prod_image_path = $file; 
       
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
       
    }

  
    public function show($id)
    {
       $product = Product::find($id);
       return view ('user.show',['product'=>$product]);
    }
  

    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        $arr['product'] = $product;
        return view('admin.products.edit')->with($arr);

    }

   
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        if($request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName())
        {
            $ext =$request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName();
            $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;
            $request->prod_image_path->storeAs('public/admin',$file);
        }else{
            $file ='';
        }
        $product-> prod_name = $request-> prod_name;
        $product-> prod_meta_title = $request-> prod_meta_title;
        $product-> prod_description = $request-> prod_description;
        $product-> prod_category = $request-> prod_category;
        $product-> prod_price = $request-> prod_price;
        $product-> prod_discount = $request-> prod_discount;
        $product-> prod_image_path = $file;
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }

    
    public function destroy($id)
    {
       Product:: destroy($id);
       return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }
}
```

This is my User ProductsController.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

     
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::get();
        return view ('index')->with(compact('products'));
      
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
      //  return view('admin.products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        // $product-> prod_name = $request-> prod_name;
        // $product->save();
        // return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
       
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        // $arr['product'] = $product;
        // return view('admin.products.edit')->with($arr);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        // $product-> prod_name = $request-> prod_name;
        // $product->update();
        // return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        // Product::destroy($id);
        // return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }
}
```

And my image path is as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your path is incorrect it should be `storage/app/admin/image_name`

Comment: Remove the space between `$p` and `[` in `$p ['prod_image_path']`

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the path, use `Storage::url(` as described here: *https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-urls`*

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created the storage link then try to get your images like this

```
<img class="img-fluid mb-1 max-width-100-sm" src="{{ url(storage/admin/'.$p ['prod_image_path'] ) }}" alt="Image Description">
```

Answer (score 0):

hi from you screen capture , look like you can store the image in storage folder succesfully .

your problem is now you dnt know how to print out the image path if I understood correctly

you may try below:
try to create a symbolic link

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

after that whatever inside storage/app/public will be access inside public/storage
so that it can render outside

if your image path is correctly saved to db , you can make a accessor like below

```
public function getProdImagePathAttribute($value)
    {
        return asset("storage/".$value) ;
    }
```

render it from blade

```
<img src="{{$model->prod_image_path}}" >
```

thanks this is how I save file image and print it out